# How do I output stderr/stdout of my script to both a file and the console?

Tags: bash, console, stdout, output, stderr

I'm using Amazon Linux and writing a script in bash.  I want to output both stderr / stdout (preferably in the order that they occur) to a file as well as the console.  However, this command isn't working ...

```
node test.js 2>&1 >> /tmp/output | tee --append /tmp/output
```

The output gets sent to the file, but it is not getting output to the console as it is happening.  How can I correct the above to view the output?

Comment: The redirection to file should be at the end of the pipeline - then you can use `tee`s to get output to terminal-screen and/or write/append to files before the final redirection.  If you had a long pipeline with many commands, you would use redirection (>) to save the final result to a file.  But you could use `tee`s to also save several of the intermediate results to files... and/or to print one of the intermediate - or the final result - to the terminal-screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `>> /tmp/output` already sends all output to the file, leaving nothing to be sent to `tee`.
So the command should read `node test.js 2>&1 | tee --append /tmp/output`.